# Values binding doesn't work in custom component

Tags: angular

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. I have a problem. 
I often use libraries that add functionality to existing components (tags). For example, thanks to the library **bootstrap-select**, 
I can enable a convenient search function on my  tag (thanks to the attribute `data-live-search`, which takes a boolean value).
The problem is that I can not assign dynamic properties to the attributes of the library.
For example, if I develop a custom component, which takes the `search` value as input:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search={{search}}>
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

The console error is:

```
Can't bind to 'live-search' since it isn't a known property of 'select'
```

This is true, since the property is added from the library, but it seems to me very inconvenient not to be able to assign a value associated with an object! It works only if I put the value `true` or `false`, 
but if I use a reference, it gives me an error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve with this custom component

Comment: the goal for which I need the component has no connection with the question asked!

Comment: I think you should have a look at the part of the error after the bit you quoted.. the solution is in there I believe..

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [attribute binding](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/attribute-binding-in-angular-6/).

`attr.data-live-search="{{search}}"`

Answer (score -1):

Can you try using brackets around data-live-search to evaluate the property?

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" [data-live-search]="search">
    <option>Option 1</option>
    <option>Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I understand that you're new to stackoverflow. This type of an answer should be a comment. Just for your knowledge, for next time.

Comment: @benshabatnoam Hear! Hear! I was going to post as a comment, but I can't since I'm a new user with less than 50 reputation.